# How to display images using the MINST dataset in keras

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

I imported the minst dataset from keras, and want to display some images from it. But since I imported the dataset from keras internally, how should I use matplotlib to display some images?

```
%matplotlib inline 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# this creates a training set and test set
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

img=mpimg.imread('x_train[1]')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot from Keras library]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image=x_train[1]
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get this error if I do this: ValueError: ('Expected image array to have rank 3 (single image). Got array with shape:', (28, 28))

Comment: @Daphne sorry forgot they are greyscale. let us do it with matplot. Check the edited ans

Comment: that works! so import matplotlib.image as mpimg is not necessary?

Comment: @Daphne Nope you dont need. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you